# Can you mix managing a static site deploy with git and ftp?

Tags: git, ftp

I have an old static site I sometimes work on that is HUGE and I'm trying to do some housekeeping and speed up git deploys. Our git deploys to various test environments is around 20 minutes each. It's kind of painful to promote changes all the way up to production.

I found a folder Friday that houses some json files that in total, approaches one gigabyte.

I would like to remove that folder from git and manage those json files via FTP (they don't need to be in any test environment, only production). Git deploys happen several times each day, every day, the json files are updated much less frequently. We don't even need versioning of these files.

The json files have to be publicly accessible at their current url, this cannot change. There is currently no resources to handle the purpose of the json files in a better way. I have asked repeatedly, so please realize we are stuck with the json files.

When we do a git push, we have a post-receive hook that does a checkout to the appropriate folder where the site is served up from:

/usr/local/apache2/path/to/site

I would be FTP'ing to this same directory, the only difference is I would be FTP'ing a directory which doesn't exist in the git repo. Let's call it www.mysite.com/data for simplicity.

My questions:

- Can I just delete the /data json folder from git, git push everything back out and then FTP the /data json folder?  Will subsequent git push/checkouts blow out the FTP'd /data json folder?
- Since git holds the entire revision history, what is the best way to purge that /data folder so I get real savings out of this work?

We also have over 8.5 gigs of pdfs that I want to start cleaning up. Luckily, this can be facilitated by year-named folders and years in file names.

It makes me think the easiest thing would be to draw a line in the sand, have a code freeze day or two, start deleting stuff and make a new repo out of the cleaned up site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this `/data` folder to the `.gitignore` file.
So you can manage this data folder with FTP and the rest of the website with Git.

Comment: Does it need to be added to .gitignore if it's removed from the repo? I really want to get it out of git and purge any revision history. Does gitignore play a part in the checkout process?

Comment: You need to put in in .gitignore if the folder are inside the git repo. If you want it out of the repo folder, you don't need. 
If it's being tracked by your repo, you can remove from it using the command:

`git rm -r --cached /data`

This will remove the folder from git tracking, and the .gitignore will ignore future changes.

Comment: Do you know the best way to remove all the revision history of /data as well? I want it all gone from the repo.

Comment: Here is tutorial how to purge your data from revision history.
https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/